# host windows console application on cloud

Tags: windows, console, cloud

I am planning to host a **Windows console program** on cloud, so that other users have access to it without downloading. However, I have no idea how to start. What cloud service should I use? Do I need to create an online interface for users?

Currently our minimum viable product is a web service--a client enters a URL, and can then directly see the console program and interact with it.

I tried Amazon EC2 t1.micro, but seemingly it just rented me a machine. I couldn't set up a website that provides the console program.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP should have service similar to that below :

http://www.citrix.com/products/xenapp/how-it-works/application-virtualization.html

or you can rent a dedicated server with ssh login and run programs though shell. But it is welcome for hackers.)

Comment: Sorry for complicating the matter--I really want a web host to run the program as well as to provide a console window on the website so that users can interact with it. As for your link, applications are run in a virtual environment on users' side, which overcomplicated the matter.

Comment: ok let have a look to your requirements: - console window on web site means that you access it through browser, but browser itself can't mimic nor provide service to seamlessly transfer input output streams of console program to user ... if there is no plugin. For link above plugin is is java. You can dig into remote desktop or xwindows putty or similar to see principles behind...

Comment: Hi AoZ, I have same requirement. Did you get the solution? If yes, could you please help me?